$n^k$ with no $1$'s for $k \le 8$.
$n = 2975$ is the least positive integer with the property that none of $n, n^2, n^3, \ldots, n^7$ contain the decimal digit $1$:
$$ \eqalign{2975^2 &= 8850625\cr
2975^3 &= 26330609375\cr
2975^4 &= 78333562890625\cr
2975^5 &= 233042349599609375\cr
2975^6 &= 693300990058837890625\cr
2975^7 &= 2062570445425042724609375\cr
}$$
but $2975^8 = 6136147075139502105712890625$ does contain the digit $1$.
Is there a positive integer $n$ such that none of $n, n^2, n^3, \ldots, n^8$ contain a $1$?  If such a number exists, then I can show that $n > 10^{11}$.
And while we're at it, are there other positive integers $n$ besides $2975 \times 10^j$ for $j \ge 0$ such that none of $n, n^2, n^3, \ldots, n^7$ contains a $1$?
See OEIS sequences A371706 and A275533.
[EDIT] I've now verified that $2975 \times 10^j$ are the only ones up to $10^{11}$.
It wasn't a completely brute-force search.  Suppose you've searched up to $n$ and found that $n^k = \sum_j d_j 10^{j-1}$ with $d_i = 1$, then that same digit will be $1$ for $n'$ if $n' < \left(10^{i-1} + \sum_{j > i} d_j 10^{j-1}\right)^{1/k}$. So the next $n$ to look at should be the maximum (over all $1$'s in the $n^k$'s) of the ceiling of those bounds.
It occurred to me that another avenue for investigation might be to consider the Cantor-type
set $E$ of real numbers in $[0,1]$ that have a decimal representation containing no $1$'s.  The question
is what points $x \in E$ have the property that
$x^k \in E$ for $k = 1 \ldots 7$ or $1 \ldots 8$.

Nice problem. My questions 1. Is the $10^{11}$ bound based on brute force or is there a clever trick to establish it ? 2. How far was the second occurence of a 7-sequence checked ?

My search limit for the second question is $10^9$. I found several cases doing the job upto $6$ but no other than the mentioned ones upto $7$.

Extended to $10^{10}$

You can find the last 12 digits of these powers by looking at the last 12 digits of n. That's 96 digits that must not be 1, which filters out roughly all but one in 24,000 last 12 digits. From the first 12 digits, you can usually calculate the first 11, 10 or 9 digits of the powers, that filters out a lot of cases again.

I just thought if you take the 10^k k digit numbers, then their first 8 powers have a total of about 36k digits, and 0.9^36 is about 0.022. So for every k, the chances of finding n with k digits are multiplied by 0.22. Which means it's not impossible but quite unlikely to find an n. 0.9^28 is 0.0523, so chances are a bit better to find 7 powers without digit 1. 0.9^21 is 0.1094, so the number of values no with k digits with the first 6 powers containing no 1 grows very slowly with k. Slowly enough that a better analysis could prove this wrong.

For the leading digit of $n^k$ to not be $1$ for $k=1\ldots$ you need that the fractional part of $\log n$ must be 'just below' either $\tfrac13$, $\tfrac12$, $\tfrac23$ or $1$, for an ever smaller margin of 'just below' as $k$ increases. For $k=8$ it yields roughly the following intervals:
$$(0.329, \tfrac13),\qquad (0.472,\tfrac12),\qquad (0.663,\tfrac23),\qquad(0.913,1).$$
Perhaps this can be refined further by looking at the second digit, etc, in the spirit of the Cantor-type set you mention.

Of course for the last digits, simple modular arithmetic excludes a lot of numbers. Just looking at the last digit excludes all numbers ending in $1$, $3$, $7$ and $9$, and with last digit $0$ we can divide by $10$. Looking at the last two digits excludes all numbers with $0$, $1$, $4$, $5$ or $9$, as their second digit, or ending in $28$, $34$, $36$, $64$, $66$, $78$, $84$ or $86$.

My computer has worked on it for a bit, and for $n < 10^{17}$ there is n = 2,975 where the first seven powers don't contain the digit 1 and no others, and no solution with 8 or 9 powers. There's a gazillion of solutions where the first 4 or 5 powers don't contain the digit 1.
I've examined the powers $n^1$ to $n^6$ for $n < 10^{16}$ and the solutions I found are n = 305, 2,975, 89,985, 999,494, 98,967,968, 976,409,524, 8,208,455,868, 86,622,736,472, 86,625,045,272, 87,343,705,474, 96,802,050,594, 777,420,594,432, 3,052,993,738,494, 7,682,926,833,335, 798,034,963,308,335, 867,924,768,666,305, 7,795,348,322,423,375, 7,895,743,460,673,905, and 7,904,758,304,653,368. Listing them not because they are particularly interesting, but if someone else implements it then they can check my list and their list of solutions. I'll start my computer in a minute to check for more solutions with $n < 10^{17}$, but that will run for a day or two. PS. n = 97,622,758,647,048,968 is a 17 digit number where none of the first 17 digits are equal to 1.
The principle is that given the last k digits of n, you can calculate the last k digits of n^2, n^3, n^4 etc. So you use brute force to find all $n < 10^9$ where the last digits of its powers don't contain the number 1, that only takes seconds.
For the solutions found, you add a digit other than 1 at the start, and check the last ten digits of the powers. Then the last 11 digits, up to the last 17 digits.
I'll have to write some more code to handle all $n < 10^{18}$ fast enough: If the calculation ends at $10^{18}$ then I can build a table of all leading four digits where no power can be guaranteed to have 1 as one of the leading digits. For example, n cannot start with 1. n cannot start with 20 because the fourth power is 160,000 starting with 1, and it cannot start with 21. It cannot start with 22 to 26 because $n^3$ starts with 1. It cannot start with 270 to 287 because of $n^4$ and so on. This saves about 2/3rds of all operations, but doesn't work if I want to extend this to more digits.
Checking the first eight powers, there are 623,307 nine digit numbers where none of the powers contains the digit 1. 44 million 12 digit numbers, 191 million 13 digit numbers, 830 million 14 digit numbers, 3.56 billion 15 digit numbers, 15 billion 16 digit numbers, and 65 billion 17 digit numbers.
Checking up to the sixth power only, there are 3,268,094 9 digit, 479 million 12 digit, 2.5 billion 13 digit, 13.5 billion 14 digit, 72 billion 15 digit, and 383 billion 16 digit numbers. So this is much harder to check. Even so it is about one in 26,000 numbers and with every digit the percentage almost halves.
Heuristically, I expect the number of k-digit solutions up to $n^6$ to grow very slowly with k; for solutions up to $n^7$ or $n^8$ that number shrinks exponentially. Still it is is possible that there are more solutions.
